# AutoARIMAProphet is slower than Prophet and less accurate

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, forecasting, forecast

AutoARIMAProphet from statsforecast (python) suggests to be faster than Prophet (with higher accuracy). Details are here: [LINK](https://github.com/Nixtla/statsforecast/tree/main/experiments/arima_prophet_adapter)

Still, it doesn't look to be quite faster nor more accurate compared to the native Prophet library.

As you can see below:

#### Versions

Python 3.10.11 -
statsforecast 1.5.0 -
prophet 1.1.4

#### Data

Data from [[Kaggle]](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/store-sales-time-series-forecasting/data)
Filename: `train.csv`

```py
family = 'GROCERY I'
store_nbr = 44

df = pd.read_csv("data_input/train.csv").drop('id', axis=1)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df_train = df.query('(family == @family) & (store_nbr == @store_nbr)').reset_index(drop=1)

cutoff = '2016-01-01'
df_test = df_train.query('date >= @cutoff').reset_index(drop=1)
df_train = df_train.query('date < @cutoff').reset_index(drop=1)
```

#### Experiment with AutoARIMAProphet:

```py
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from statsforecast.adapters.prophet import AutoARIMAProphet

def process_df_train(df):
    df = df.rename({'sales': "y", 'date': 'ds'}, axis=1)
    return df.sort_values('ds', ascending=True)

start = time.time()
aaprophet = AutoARIMAProphet()
aaprophet.fit(process_df_train(df_train), disable_seasonal_features=False)
print("Train:", time.time() - start)

aap_pred = aaprophet.make_future_dataframe(periods=593)
aap_pred = aaprophet.predict(aap_pred)
print("Pred:", time.time() - start)
```

Output:

```
Train: 8.129928588867188  # Time for training
Pred: 8.15820026397705  # Time until prediction ends
```

FA score:

```py
df_plot = (aap_pred
           .rename({'ds': 'date'}, axis=1)
           .merge(df_train[['date', 'sales']].rename({'sales': 'sales_train'}, axis=1), on='date', how='outer')
           .merge(df_test[['date', 'sales']].rename({'sales': 'sales_test'}, axis=1), on='date', how='outer')
          )

def compute_fa(pred):
    return 1 - np.abs(np.sum(pred['yhat'] - pred['sales_test'])) / np.sum(pred['sales_test'])

compute_fa(df_plot)
```

Output:

```
0.8975427859368323
```

#### Experiment with native Prophet:

```py
from prophet import Prophet 

def process_df_train(df):
    df = df.rename({'sales': "y", 'date': 'ds'}, axis=1)
    return df.sort_values('ds', ascending=True)

start = time.time()
aaprophet = Prophet()
aaprophet.fit(process_df_train(df_train))
print("Train:", time.time() - start)

aap_pred = aaprophet.make_future_dataframe(periods=593)
aap_pred = aaprophet.predict(aap_pred)
print("Pred:", time.time() - start)
```

Output:

```
Train: 0.15532231330871582
Pred: 0.7572097778320312
```

FA score:

```py
df_plot = (aap_pred
           .rename({'ds': 'date'}, axis=1)
           .merge(df_train[['date', 'sales']].rename({'sales': 'sales_train'}, axis=1), on='date', how='outer')
           .merge(df_test[['date', 'sales']].rename({'sales': 'sales_test'}, axis=1), on='date', how='outer')
          )
1 - np.abs(np.sum(df_plot['yhat'] - df_plot['sales_test'])) / np.sum(df_plot['sales_test'])
```

Output:

```
0.9119373623344371
```

Has anyone run into this? It's still the same on other datasets (other than the benchmark the authors made). Am I missing something?